# Is there a way to not show scientific notation in pandas for numeric values?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I queried my postgres database to retrieve information from a table:

```
SQLResults = cursor.execute('SELECT x.some_12_long_integer from test as x;')
```

Now when I run this query in database, I get `1272140958198`, but when I dump this in a dataframe:

The `x.some_12_long_integer` is int8.

I am using xlsxwriter:

```
excel_writer =  ExcelWriter(
    self.fullFilePath, engine="xlsxwriter",
    engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_numbers': True}}
)

frame = DataFrame(SQLResults[0])
frame.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)
```

When it is converted to Excel it produces `1.27214E+12` but when I format the cell in the Excel file I get `1272140958198`.

How can I make it just stay as `1272140958198` instead of `1.27214E+12`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to disable scientific notation in pandas. However, there are a few ways to work around this:

Convert the numeric values to strings using .to_string() . This will remove the scientific notation and provide a more user-friendly representation of the data. Perform mathematical operations on the numeric values in order to round them off to a specific number of decimal places. This will remove most of the scientific notation, but some may still remain.